# Switch Tag On Text Box

Tags: c#, button, textbox, tags, click

I am trying to change the textbox text if I click the button:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     string Tag = (string)button1.Tag;

        switch (Tag)
        {
            case "quest1_1":
                textBox1.Text = "test";
                button1.Tag = "quest1_2";
                break;

            case "quest1_2":
                textbox1.Text = "example text";
                button1.Tag = "quest1_3";
                break;

            default:
                textbox1.Text = "";
                button1.Tag = "";
                break;
        }
        }
```

The problem is that this code worked in another project but here it doesn't.
If I start the application and click button1, nothing happens.

Can you help me with that?

Comment: _"nothing happens"_ Does your IDE have a debugger? If so, have you ever used it? If so, replace _nothing happens_ with what actually happened.

Comment: My IDE is Visual Studio and I used its debugger some minutes ago. I mean with nothing happens that textBox1 is clear

Answer (score 0):

1. Is button1_Click a listener on the button's click event?  Set a breakpoint in this routine and see if you get there when you click.
2. Is button1.Tag set to anything by default?  The debugger will tell you that, too.

Comment: 1. You mean break; ?                2.  Yes it's set to nothing ("")

Answer (score 0):

If the tag of the button is set to "" it is neither the case "quest1_1" nor the case "quest1_2", it is the default case. In your default you use this:

```
textbox1.Text = "";
button1.Tag 
break;
```

Which means setting the textbox text to nothing, so it is pretty normal that nothing happens.

Comment: Uh, thanks, Den! I changed the default content, now it's working!